# Form hidden value not being posted

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a form which I want to post to my PHP file.  The form consists of the submit button and a hidden value which contains the value of a localStorage entry:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="formAnswers" id="localStorageAnswers" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
    $("#localStorageAnswers").val(localStorage.getItem(answers));
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['formAnswers'])) {
   echo $_POST['formAnswers'];
}
```

When the PHP file is launched no answers are shown.  At first I thought maybe It wouldn't set it on the `on('click')` but I've set the value at a sooner point on the page with no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `answers` is not a variable, but a keyword. Use `localStorage.getItem("answers")` instead of `localStorage.getItem(answers)`

Comment: Spent ages trying to figure it out.  Knew it would be something stupid.  Thanks a million.

Comment: With pleasure. If the answer solves the problem, then you can accept it.

Comment: Was just waiting for it to let me.  Thanks again.